# Mailchimp PHP API variables not sending

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am just trying to figure out why this won't work. It sends to MailChimp with the API but has some problem with the way it received the email address. If I send just a string like the second example, it works fine.

Something must be wrong in my formatting, any ideas. I tried with variables I set, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks

```
//SEND INFO TO MAILCHIMP
                $MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp($api);
                $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                                'id'                => 'e659124bf2',
                                'email'     => array('email'=> $_POST['email']),
                                'merge_vars'        => array('FNAME'=>$_POST['usersName'], 'LNAME'=>$_POST['usersLastName']),
                                'double_optin'      => false,
                                'update_existing'   => true,
                                'replace_interests' => false,
                                'send_welcome'      => false,
                            ));
                print_r($result);
```

But if I put simple strings in it works fine:

```
//SEND INFO TO MAILCHIMP
                $MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp($api);
                $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                                'id'                => 'e659124bf2',
                                'email'     => array('email'=> 'exampe@example.com),
                                'merge_vars'        => array('FNAME'=> 'John', 'LNAME'=>'smith'),
                                'double_optin'      => false,
                                'update_existing'   => true,
                                'replace_interests' => false,
                                'send_welcome'      => false,
                            ));
                print_r($result);
```

Comment: submit the form from your first example and do `print_r($_POST);` to make sure you're getting the right variables and the right data

Comment: thanks that did help, I realized a dumb error.